# eclipse 4.3 on mac hangs when turning off validation?

Tags: eclipse, macos

I just installed eclipse 4.3 EE version on a mac; and when i go to "preferences" and "validation", and i try to turn off some of the xml validation, clicking on one of the check boxes causes eclipse to simply hang. I get the spinning disk and have to force quit eclipse.

Anybody know of a workaround?

Comment: Looks like this bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=412826  High priority but no fix or workaround yet.

Comment: ok, looks like a workaround is to right click on the check box, then you get a menu with "build", and "manual" and you can click one of the entries.